# Как расположить несколько фреймов в столбец и scrollbar к ним?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Имеется группа сходных фреймов с некими элементами. Хочу расположить эти фреймы в виде колонки со скроллбаром справа и всю эту конструкцию упаковать в один всеобъемлющий фрейм.

Делаю так:

```
frame = Frame(mainWindow) # фрейм в котором будет расположен столбец фреймов с скроллом
frame.grid()
listbox = Listbox(dialogsFrame)
listbox.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y)
scroll = Scrollbar(dialogsFrame)
scroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
scroll.config(command = listbox.yview)
```

И затем я в `listbox` упаковываю мои фреймы типа `frames[i].grid(row = i, column = 0)`. В итоге получается нужная конструкция, однако скроллбар не работает. Т.е. на нём нет ползунка и он вообще не активен. При этом, по умолчанию размер `frame` оказывается достаточен для того, чтобы на скроллбаре не было ползунка (т.е. все подфреймы видны). При изменении размера окна добиться появления ползунка не удаётся. Скроллбар хочется иметь, т.к. возможен случай когда подфреймов будет слишком много и окошко вылезет за пределы монитора.

Как это сделать?

Кроме исходного фрейма в окне могут располагаться другие элементы. Хочется сделать конструкцию независящей от размеров этих элементов и самого фрейма. Т.е., если пользовытель изменяет размер окна, то в определённый момент (если высота окна слишком маленькая) скроллбар активируется. Хочется только задать ограничение на само окно, например, установить высоту окна в некую долю от разрешения по вертикали, и ограничения на размер некоторых элементов, соседствующих с фреймом, а сам фрейм пусть изменяется как хочет, только чтобы скроллбар появлялся и корректно работал.

UDP[26.02.2016]: нашёл [этот пример на английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/python-tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame). На его основе сделал следующий тестовый код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

topButton = Button(root, text = 'Кнопка сверху')
topButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
lowFrame = Frame(root)
lowFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

canvas = Canvas(lowFrame)
frame = Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar = Scrollbar(lowFrame, orient = 'vertical', command = canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = myscrollbar.set)
myscrollbar.pack(side = 'right', fill = Y)
canvas.pack(side = 'left')
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = frame, anchor = 'nw')
def conf(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox('all'))
frame.bind('<Configure>', conf)

for i in range(50):
    b = Button(frame, text = str(i))
    b.grid(row = i, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Он вполне работает, однако возникли пара вопросов:

1. Что делает `canvas.create_window()`? Что это за окно, где оно создаётся?
2. Мы биндим `frame.bind('<Configure>', conf)`. Можно проверить что событие происходит каждый раз при использовании скролла. Почему при использовании скролла происходит событие, связанное со фреймом?
3. Что делает эта штука: `canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox('all'))`? Почему её необходимо выполнять каждый раз при скролле, почему недостаточно выполнить один раз при инициализации программы?
4. Нет ли способа забиндить событие (см. 2 и 3) без явного определения дополнительной функции в программе? Заюзать лямбда-выражения, или что-то в таком духе?

Comment: Я думаю, listbox тут ни к чему. Нужно просто взять scrollbar и правильно прикрутить.

Comment: Я переделал этот пример: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm

Comment: И вот здесь (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm) тоже указано что скролл только к листбоксу прикручивается. Text, Entry для текста, Canvas вообще для картинок.

Comment: Там написано, что Scrollbar **почти всегда** используется вместе с Listbox, Canvas, или TextBox. Само по себе это предложение не отрицает возможности использовать Scrollbar отдельно от них, либо как-то по-другому (например, вместе с фреймом, хотя это будет не так удобно). При использовании с Listbox состояние Scrollbar'а зависит от добавленных в него текстовых строк, а не налепленных на него элементов управления.

Answer (score 2):

1. Метод [`canvas.create_window()`](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method) создает область на объекте `canvas`, в которую можно разместить виджет (в данном случае фрейм). Для области, созданной с помощью `create_window` можно определить очерчивающий прямоугольник (bounding box) с помощью `canvas.bbox('all')`. Если виджеты размещать напрямую на холсте, то они не будут учитываться при расчете очерчивающего прямоугольника.
2. Событие `<Configure>` срабатывает при изменении размера и положения виджета (в данном случае виджета `frame`), видимо в том числе и при прокрутке скролла. См. [Events and Bindings](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).
3. `canvas.configure(scrollregion = ...)` задает "прокручиваемый" (управляемый скроллом) прямоугольник внутри `canvas`. В данном случае это `canvas.bbox('all')` (bbox - bounding box - ограничивающий прямоугольник, т.е. прямоугольник, в который попадает все содержимое), `'all'` - это тег, который прикреплен ко всем элементам на `canvas` - фигурам и виджетам (см. [Item Specifiers: Handles and Tags](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#item-specifiers)).

   - Это действие нужно, чтобы задать для `canvas` прокручиваемую область на основе размера размещенного на `canvas` фрейма. Окончательный размер фрейм приобретает после фактического добавления всех кнопок, и похоже, что это происходит уже в процессе выполнения `mainloop()`. Можно это повторяемое действие заменить на строку `root.after(100, lambda: canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox('all')))`, но надежнее все-таки делать через привязку к событию `<Config>` (особенно если вы в процессе работы программы будете добавлять виджеты на фрейм)
4. `frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox('all')))`