# Можно ли в tkinter биндить на одно событие два разных обработчика?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Сколько максимально обработчиков можно забиндить в одном вызове `.bind()` ?

Comment: @insolor К сожалению, Вы ошибаетесь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На одно событие в *Tkinter* можно биндить столько обработчиков, сколько нам захочется. Если ограничение на их количество и есть, то оно связано только с физическими ограничениями среды.

Если посмотреть в документацию на функцию [`bind`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events), то мы увидим, что у неё есть параметр `add`. Вот что написано про него в документации:

> is optional, either '' or '+'. Passing an empty string denotes that this binding is to replace any other bindings that this event is associated with. Passing a '+' means that this function is to be added to the list of functions bound to this event type.

Перевод:

> Необязательный параметр. Может быть равным либо '', либо '+'. Передача пустой строки означает, что новая связь заменит все связи с событием, установленные ранее. Передача '+' означает, что функция будет добавлена к списку функций, связанных с указанным событием.

По умолчанию `add=''`, Поэтому новая функция заменяет предыдущую.

Вот минимальный пример связывания нескольких функций с одним событием:

```
import tkinter


def handler1(event):
    print("Handler 1.")


def handler2(event):
    print("Handler 2.")

tk = tkinter.Tk()

button = tkinter.Button(tk, text="Button")
button.bind("<Button>", handler1)
button.bind("<Button>", handler2, '+')
button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Офигенно! Спасибо. Если есть возможность, прошу взглянуть ещё на [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496427/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%86-%D0%B8-scrollbar-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2-python-tkinter) (UPD)