# Получение привязанной функции tkinter bind

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter

К движению мыши привязана функция. В последующем требуется привязать к нему еще одну функцию. Но напрямую это невозможно. Поэтому, чтобы привязать и вторую, нам нужно создать собирательную функцию, неважно, с именем или безымянную.

Но в случае, когда эти 2 функции находятся в разных классах, мы не можем просто взять и создать рандомную функцию посреди всего, нужно эту функцию создавать в моменте. А так как нам по умолчанию недоступна уже привязанная функция, то ее нужно как то получить из того виджета, к которому она привязана.

Мне нужно что-то вроде `canvas.get_bind()`, а в полном виде с этой функцией:
`lambda event: [canvas.get_bind(event), another_func(event)]`

Полный код:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class MouseTracker(tk.Label):
    
    def __init__(self, widget, master=None, label='({}, {})', **options):
        super().__init__(master, **options)
        if label.count('{}') == 2:
            self.label = label
        else:
            self.label = '({}, {})'
        widget.bind('<Motion>', self.mouse_motion)
        widget.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.mouse_motion)
        self['text'] = self.label.format(0, 0)
    
    def mouse_motion(self, event):
        self.coord = event.x, event.y
        self['text'] = self.label.format(*self.coord)


class DotCreator:
    
    def __init__(self, canvas, total_dots=5):
        self.dots = []
        self.total_dots = 5
        self.canvas = canvas
        
    def new_dot(self, event):
        x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
        x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
        self.canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='#fff', outline="")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='grey', width=500, height=500)
    canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', DotCreator(canvas).new_dot)
    canvas.grid(column=0, row=1)
    
    widget = MouseTracker(canvas, root, label='{} | {}', font='Arial 20')
    widget.grid(column=0, row=0)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

А именно нужно привязать `[MouseTracker().mouse_motion(event), DotCreator().new_dot(event)]`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497578/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-tkinter-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Благодарю, не знал про это, в других вопросах утверждали обратное