# Скроллинг виджета Radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6, scrollbar

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать скроллинг виджета Radiobutton?

Пробовал сделать через Canvas:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

canvas_result = Canvas(root)
scrollbar_result = Scrollbar(root, orient = 'vertical')
scrollbar_result['command'] = canvas_result.yview
canvas_result.place(y = "0", width  = 150, height = 300)
scrollbar_result.place(x = 150,y = "0", height = 300)

res = StringVar()
row = 0

for i in range(20):
    result_rad = Radiobutton(canvas_result, text = i, value = i, variable = res)
    result_rad.place(y = row)
    row += 20

root.mainloop()
```

В результате полоска скроллинга появляется, но не работает.

Также пробовал в Canvas добавлять Label и выводить Radiobutton в Label, результат тот же.

Comment: В этом вопросе есть рабочий пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496427/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%86-%D0%B8-scrollbar-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2-python-tkinter

Comment: Отформатируйте код, пожалуйста, в соответствии с PEP-ами. Читать невозможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал следующим образом:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() 

lowFrame = Frame(root)
lowFrame.place(y='0', width = '200', height = '400')

canvas = Canvas(lowFrame)
frame = Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar = Scrollbar(lowFrame, orient = 'vertical', command = canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = myscrollbar.set)
myscrollbar.place(x = '100', y='0', height = '200')
canvas.place(x='0',y='0', width = '50', height = '200')
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = frame, anchor = 'nw')

def conf(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox('all'))

frame.bind('<Configure>', conf)

for i in range(50):
    b = Radiobutton(frame, text = i,value = i)
    b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Но почему-то пункты сдвигаются в левую сторону(((