# Почему не работает scrollbar в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Lightshot stealer')
root.geometry('{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}'.format(1000,
                                       600,
                                       int((root.winfo_screenwidth()-1000)/2),
                                       int((root.winfo_screenheight()-600)/2)))
root.resizable(False, False)
toolbar = tk.Frame(root, bg='#fafafa', bd=2, height=40)
toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

#scrollbar
images_canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bd=2)
images_canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(images_canvas, orient="vertical")
scrollbar['command'] = images_canvas.yview
images_canvas['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
scrollbar.place(x=950, y=50)

label_last_url = tk.Label(toolbar, text='Последние символы URL: ', bg='#fafafa')
label_last_url.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
entry_last_url = tk.Entry(toolbar)
entry_last_url.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
label_amount_images = tk.Label(toolbar, text='Количество изображений: ', bg='#fafafa')
label_amount_images.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
entry_amount_images = tk.Entry(toolbar)
entry_amount_images.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
button_download = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Скачать', bg='#fafafa', font='Arial 12')
button_download.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=15)
img = Image.open('all.jpg')
img = img.resize((150, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
counter = 0
y = 1
for _ in range(40):
    if y == 7:
        y = 1
        counter += 1
    button_image = tk.Button(images_canvas, image=image)
    button_image.grid(row=counter, column=y)
    y += 1
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Только измененные куски:

```
#scrollbar
images_canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bd=2)
# Скроллбар кладем на само окно (root) по правой стороне
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical")
scrollbar['command'] = images_canvas.yview
images_canvas['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
# Делаем чтобы холст заполнял все оставшееся место (expand=True)
images_canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# ...

# Фрейм для размещения кнопок
frame = tk.Frame(images_canvas)
# Фрейм кладется внутрь "окна" (области?) на холсте
images_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor='nw')

counter = 0
y = 1
for _ in range(40):
    if y == 7:
        y = 1
        counter += 1
    button_image = tk.Button(frame, image=image)  # кнопки крепим к фрейму, а не к холсту
    button_image.grid(row=counter, column=y)
    y += 1

# Обновляем прокручиваемую область холста
def conf(event):
    images_canvas.configure(scrollregion=images_canvas.bbox('all'))

frame.bind('<Configure>', conf)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Анимашка]

За основу взят код из вопроса: [Несколько фреймов в столбец и scrollbar к ним](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496427/1365)