# Координаты виджета Entry(canvas) при перемещении

Tags: python, tkinter

Сделал прокрутку объектов на canvas через метод canvas.move() - изменение координат объекта при прокрутке колесиком мышки (`canvas2.bind_all("MouseWheel", fun_mooving)`). Получилось всё хорошо, все объекты (canvas.create_text, canvas.create_image) перемещаются как им и положено. Но проблема всплыла, когда добавляю на канвас несколько объектов типа Entry(canvas). Если плавно крутить колесо мышки, то заметно небольшое запаздывание при перемещение объектов Entry, при этом другие объекты (тексты, картинки) перемещаются без проблем, как им и положено. Если колесо мышки крутить резко, то координаты при перемещении Entry могут сбиваться капитально - не вставать на положенные им координаты. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*

global v_entry

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x800+10+10')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def xxx():
    global v_entry, list_v
    txt1 = 'txt1txt1txt1txt1txt1txt1txt1'
    v_01 = canvas2.create_text(30, 10, text=txt1)
    v_entry[0] =Entry(canvas2)
    (v_entry[0]).insert(0, '000')
    (v_entry[0]).place(x=100, y=25)

    txt1 = 'txt2txt2txt2txt2txt2txt2txt2'
    v_02 = canvas2.create_text(30, 50, text=txt1)
    v_entry[1] =Entry(canvas2)
    (v_entry[1]).insert(0, '101')
    (v_entry[1]).place(x=100, y=75)

    txt1 = 'txt3txt3txt3txt3txt3txt3txt3'
    v_03 = canvas2.create_text(30, 100, text=txt1)
    v_entry[2] =Entry(canvas2)
    (v_entry[2]).insert(0, '202')
    (v_entry[2]).place(x=100, y=125)

    txt1 = 'txt4txt4txt4txt4txt4txt4txt4'
    v_04 = canvas2.create_text(30, 150, text=txt1)
    v_entry[3] =Entry(canvas2)
    (v_entry[3]).insert(0, '303')
    (v_entry[3]).place(x=100, y=175)

    txt1 = 'txt5txt5txt5txt5txt5txt5txt5'
    v_05 = canvas2.create_text(30, 200, text=txt1)
    v_entry[4] =Entry(canvas2)
    (v_entry[4]).insert(0, '404')
    (v_entry[4]).place(x=100, y=225)

    txt1 = 'tx6txt6txt6txt6txt6txt6txt6'
    v_06 = canvas2.create_text(30, 250, text=txt1)
    v_entry[5] =Entry(canvas2)
    (v_entry[5]).insert(0, '505')
    (v_entry[5]).place(x=100, y=275)

    txt1 = 'tx7txt7tx7txt7txt7txt7txt7'
    v_07 = canvas2.create_text(30, 300, text=txt1)
    v_entry[6] =Entry(canvas2)
    (v_entry[6]).insert(0, '606')
    (v_entry[6]).place(x=100, y=325)

    txt1 = 'tx8txt8txt8txt8txt8txt8txt8'
    v_08 = canvas2.create_text(30, 350, text=txt1)


    list_v = [v_01, v_02, v_03, v_04, v_05, v_06, v_07, v_08]

def fun_mooving(event):              #прокрутка объектов на canvas2
    global v_entry, list_v

    y=int(event.delta/2)

    for i1 in list_v:
        canvas2.move(i1, 0, y)


    for i in v_entry:        
        y1 = i.winfo_y()
        y1 += y        
        i.place(x = 100, y = y1)


canvas1 = Canvas(root, width=600, height=800, highlightthickness=0)    
canvas1.place(x=0, y=0)

canvas2 = Canvas(canvas1, width=600, height=750, highlightthickness=0)
canvas2.place(x=0, y=50)

v_entry = []
for i in range (7): 
    v_entry.append(Entry(canvas2, bd = 0, justify = CENTER, width = 6))

xxx()
canvas2.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", fun_mooving)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать прокрутку элементов управления на холсте при помощи скролбара, посмотрите пример в этом вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496427/1365

Comment: Упаковывание всего во фреймы меня не устраивает - у него есть прозрачность, но нет возможности вставить текст или картинку, как в canvas, а если текст и картинку размещать на Label, то у них нет прозрачности. Прозрачность для меня критичный вопрос. Проблему решил привязав намертво к координатам canvas.create_text в функции скроллинга

Comment: y1 = canvas2.bbox(list_v[0])[1] 
x1 =v_entry[0].winfo_x()           
v_entry[0].place_forget()          
v_entry[0].place(x = x1, y = y1)

Comment: Тогда оберните каждый Entry в окно (create_window), остальное как в ссылке. Не пишите код в комментариях, лучше добавить в вопрос.