# Не работает Scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter

Программа должна по нажатию кнопки добавлять Label с текстом. Когда количество Label становится столько, что они не помещаются в окно, должен включаться скролл, но этого не происходит
Я пробовала добавить pack_propagate(False), чтобы ограничить фрейм, но тогда в окне просто ничего не появлялось.

```
from tkinter import *


class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.number = 0

        self.f = Frame(master)
        self.f.pack()

        self.c = Canvas(self.f, bg='white')
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.f, command=self.c.yview)
        self.c.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)
        self.c.pack()

        self.b = Button(self.c, text='Press', command=self.func)
        self.b.pack()

    def func(self):
        self.number += 1
        l = Label(self.c, text="Какой то текст {}".format(self.number))
        l.pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
main = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно внутри canvas создать область ("окно"), в которой уже размещать элементы управления. При изменении виджета (фрейма), привязанного к этой области задавать свойство scrollregion (область прокрутки) холста, тогда полоса прокрутки будет менять свое состояние при добавлении элементов:

```
from tkinter import *


class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.number = 0

        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg='white')
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.frame, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.scroll.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.inner_frame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.inner_frame, anchor=NW)

        button = Button(self.inner_frame, text='Press', command=self.func)
        button.pack()

        def conf(event):
            # Обработчик срабатывает при изменении размера inner_frame
            # Задаем область прокрутки, включающую в себя все объекты на холсте
            self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

        self.inner_frame.bind('<Configure>', conf)

    def func(self):
        self.number += 1
        label = Label(self.inner_frame, text="Какой то текст {}".format(self.number))
        label.pack()


root = Tk()
# root.geometry('600x400')
main = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Примерное объяснение см. в этом ответе: [Несколько фреймов в столбец и scrollbar к ним](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/776837/1365)

Также добавил параметры для `pack`, так что холст расширяется на все окно, и вместе с полосой прокрутки адекватно себя ведет при изменении размеров окна, поэтому не обязательно жестко задавать размер окна.