# Как добавить scrollbar python, использовал для кода grid?

Tags: python

Простите я новичок, пробовал сделать скрол бар для своего окна tkinter, использовал пример ниже, только он создает текст_бокс, и размещает скрол бар к нему, а мне нужен скрол бар именно по всему окну tkinter, метод grid

```
from tkinter import *

ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.config(bg='#5F734C')

frame = Frame(
    ws,
    bg='#A8B9BF'
    )

text_box = Text(
    ws,
    height=13,
    width=32, 
    font=(12)  
)

text_box.grid(row=0, column=0)
text_box.config(bg='#D9D8D7')

sb = Scrollbar(
    ws,
    orient=VERTICAL
    )

sb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)

text_box.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
sb.config(command=text_box.yview)


ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: Что именно не получается? Если возникает ошибка - напишите какая именно ошибка возникает.

Comment: @insolor точнее сказать, не знаю как добавить скролбар

Comment: Точно так же как любой другой виджет, как button или labal, или entry

Comment: @insolor, я пробую вот таким способом, только тут скрол на текст_бокс идет, а мне нужно на все окно ткинтер, я не понимаю, как сделать
frame = Frame(
    root,
    bg='#A8B9BF'
    )

text_box = Text(
    root,
    height=13,
    width=32, 
    font=(12)  
)

text_box.grid(row=0, column=0)
text_box.config(bg='#D9D8D7')

sb = Scrollbar(
    root,
    orient=VERTICAL
    )

sb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)

text_box.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
sb.config(command=text_box.yview)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос именно тот код, как вы пытаетесь добавить scrollbar (именно тот код, с которым у вас возникла проблема), а не вашу кучу entry и label

Comment: @insolor Посмотрите пожалйуста

Comment: Если вам нужно прокручивать много контролов, нужно поместить их в фрейм, этот фрейм поместить в Canvas (с помощью create_window), потом Canvas уже прокручивать. Пример смотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1095758/1365

Comment: @insolor
Я же сказал, использую метод grid, а не канвас

Comment: Без Canvas сможете сделать прокрутку только самого текстового поля.

Comment: Т.е. можно с помощью place фрейм с контролами двигать и вручную вычислять параметры сколбара, но через Canvas менее геморно (если вариант с Canvas вам кажется геморным, вы ошибаетесь)

Comment: можно наверно это все в фрейм запихнуть и к нему уже скролбар делать

Answer (score 1):

Вот вроде то что вы просили. Если например не использовать грид , а использовать pack, то можно сделать чтобы оно на все окно расширялось при любой размере. а сейчас можно ограничить размеры окна. Реализовано по схеме как в комментариях, надеюсь поможет

```
from tkinter import *

ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.config(bg='#5F734C')



canvas = Canvas(ws, bg='#5F734C', width=183)
scroll = Scrollbar(ws, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

frame = Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor=NW)


def conf(event):
            
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

frame.bind('<Configure>', conf)

text_box = Text(
    frame,
    height=20,
    width=20, 
    font=(12)  
)

text_box.grid(row=0, column=0)
text_box.config(bg='#D9D8D7')
butt = Button(frame, text='567')
butt.grid(row=1, column=0)


ws.mainloop()
```