# Можно ли добавить scrollbar к фрейму в tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Можно ли сделать `scrollbar` для фрейма без холстов? Я находил ответы на эту тему но они были очень древними и там везде писали что нужно создать холст и внутри него поместить фреймы

Comment: [2016 год](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496427) - это не так уж давно было, tkinter  с тех пор особо не изменился. Ответ: простым путем - через холст, сложным - через отдельный scrollbar и ручное перемещение фрейма при прокрутке скролбара.

Comment: @insolor а можно ли заюзать холст в качестве фрейма? То есть поместить в холст поля и для холста сделать скроллбар.

Comment: Как в коде по ссылке выше: через create_window к холсту прикретить Frame, и его крутить. Напрямую на холст расположить виджеты можно, но крутить их не получится.

Comment: @insolor хорошо, спасибо за ответ